# Firefox ignores inline CSS in SVG, chrome displays it

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I've been working on an animated logo in SVG, it's pretty simple. I trigger it with a javascript function, animate().

When i run animate() in chrome, the styles successfully apply and the logo displays, but when i do the same in firefox it fails.

i also noted that the inline  block in my SVG is not applied, regardless of where i place it in the document, hence i concluded it must be a problem with inline CSS.

Here is my current code :

```html
<svg xmlns:osb="http://www.openswatchbook.org/uri/2009/osb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="svg8">
<defs>
  <style>
  .rect{
  height:0px;
  transition:height 1s ease;}
  </style>
</defs>
  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0 -197)" fill-opacity=".617" stroke-width="13.229">
    <rect class="rect" id="logo-2" width="16.611" x="-120.759" y="-266.945" ry="8.305" transform="rotate(-165)" opacity=".71" fill="#ff584a"/>
    <rect class="rect" id="logo-1" width="16.611" x="-40.446" y="205.589" ry="8.305" transform="rotate(-15)" opacity=".71" fill="#ff584a"/>
    <rect class="rect" id="logo-3" width="16.611" x="-6.786" y="214.383" ry="8.305" transform="rotate(-15)" opacity=".71" fill="#0a3fa6"/>
  </g>
  <script>
  function animate(){
    document.getElementById('logo-1').style="height:83.055px;";
    document.getElementById('logo-2').style="height:83.055px;";
    document.getElementById('logo-3').style="height:83.055px;";
    console.log("IT WORKS");
  }
  </script>

</svg>
```

Interestingly in the firefox inspector, the CSS is applied, however in the document itsself nothing changes...

I'm not sure if this is a bug with firefox or intended behavior, or i'm doing something wrong in my code, any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Having width, height, x and y of rect elements be CSS properties that can be animated with CSS animations is a new feature of the SVG 2 specification. In SVG 1.1 such things were attributes and could only be animated with javascript and SMIL.

Fortunately Firefox has just implemented this part of SVG 2 and from Firefox 69 this will work as you wish. You can try a [nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/channel/desktop/) right now if you wish to test it.

You can either wait or convert the animation to SMIL.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Longson mention is his answer, for now you can't animate the height of SVG elements using CSS.

This is how you can do it using SMIL animations:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="svg8">

   <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
        .rect{
    stroke:black;}
        ]]> 
  </style>

  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0 -197)" fill-opacity=".617" stroke-width="13.229">
    <rect class="rect" id="logo-2" width="16.611" x="-120.759" y="-266.945" ry="8.305" height="0" transform="rotate(-165)" opacity=".71" fill="#ff584a">
      <animate 
       attributeName="height"
       attributeType="XML"
       values="0;83.055"
       dur=".5s"
       fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
    <rect class="rect" id="logo-1" width="16.611" x="-40.446" y="205.589" ry="8.305" height="0"  transform="rotate(-15)" opacity=".71" fill="#ff584a">
      <animate 
       attributeName="height"
       attributeType="XML"
       values="0;83.055"
       dur=".5s"
       fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
    <rect class="rect" id="logo-3" width="16.611" x="-6.786" y="214.383" ry="8.305" height="0" transform="rotate(-15)" opacity=".71" fill="#0a3fa6">
      <animate 
       attributeName="height"
       attributeType="XML"
       values="0;83.055"
       dur=".5s"
       fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
  </g>
  

</svg>
```